# beautifulsoup filtering descendents using regex

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use beautiful-soup to return elements of the DOM that contain children that match filtering criteria.

In the example below,I want to return both `divs` based on finding a regex match in a child element.

```
<body>
<div class="randomclass1">
    <span class="randomclass">regexmatch1</span>
    <h2>title</h2>
</div>
<div class="randomclass2">
    <span class="randomclass">regexmatch2</span>
    <h2>title</h2>
</div>
</body>
```

The basic code setup is as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
page = soup(html)
Results = page.find_all('div')
```

How do I add a regex test that evaluates the children of the target div? I.e, how would I add the regex call below to the 'find' or 'find_all' functions of beautiful-soup?

re.compile('regexmatch\d')

Comment: you don't need regex, simply  use bs4 to get the result, which part of the html are you trying to output?

Comment: I'm trying to return both divs - but in the real use case there are many similar divs, with identical or regularly changing css selectors, and they are difficult to target. Could you use use bs4 in the example above, knowing that the text in the span tag is the only usefully unique characteristic of the target div?

Comment: get the first div then run for loop on all divs

Comment: Getting the first div will work on the code above, however, because the "real" use case can be much more complicated, I do in fact need to find a regex match, and then find the parent element, as described in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  approach I landed with was find_parent, which will return the parent element of the beautifulsoup results regardless of the method used to find the original result (regex or otherwise). For the example above:

```
childOfResults = page.find_all('span', string=re.compile('regexmatch\d'))
Results = childOfResult[0].find_parent()
```

...modified with the loop of your choice to cycle through all the members of childOfResult

Answer (score 0):

*Get the first `div` then run for loop on all `div's`*

*Example*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<body>
           <div class="randomclass1">
               <span class="randomclass">regexmatch1</span>
               <h2>title</h2>
           </div>
           <div class="randomclass2">
               <span class="randomclass">regexmatch2</span>
               <h2>title</h2>
           </div>
       </body>"""

page_soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features='html.parser')
elements = page_soup.select('body > div')

for element in elements:
    print(element.select("span:nth-child(1)")[0].text)
```

*it prints out*

```
regexmatch1
regexmatch2
```